Substitution modeling under simulated inventory constraints
In the context of retail, substitution is typically defined as "when customers that prefer product A, but when unavailable, purchase product B, instead."
Naively, the most of useful covariate might be inventory levels of product A. If we observe a lower inventory of A coupled with increased purchases of B, the latter is likely a substitute.
In my context, I'm evaluating a logistics change that will reduce the inventory levels of product A. Pessimistically, we lose demand for A with no increase to B. But optimistically, B is purchased, assuming inventory is available.
The end goal is to simulate the effect on aggregate demand given this logistic change. In other words, we are not interested in executing the logistic policy change and running an RCT, but rather simulating likely outcomes in advance of such a change.
At this stage, I'm not certain whether a causal model is indeed necessary or if pure prediction is sufficient. Suppose some black box model could predict whether B will be purchased given covariates, including inventory level of A.
Simulations might leverage this black box model to give a naive estimate of the effect on aggregate demand. However, I'm not certain about the trustworthiness of this approach.
In general, is a causal model required for substitution modeling or is a purely predictive model adequate?

I personally am fine with a purely predictive model. A couple of comments: (1) "Lower" inventory of A should really not have an impact, it's only when the inventory of A reaches zero that people switch to B. Why would you switch to B as long as there is as much A left as you want, even if the inventory of A is low? (2) Relevant considerations include whether inventory is actually sellable (and not spoilt, past its best by date, or broken), and whether you actually have the correct inventory (IRI: Inventory Record Inaccuracy).

(3) It gets worse: if A is out of stock, people will usually switch to different pack size A', A'', A''', or a different product B, or substitute C, D, ..., all of which may be available in the same size as the one people wanted originally, or a different size B', B'', C', C'', C''', ... (4) People may well respond by not switching, but by leaving the store and buying A at the competitor store. Finally, people may forego the purchase altogether, see Corsten & Gruen (2004, HBR). Bottom line: detecting substitution effects of stockouts on A (which we may not even know, see 2 above) is hard.
